# How would I style a webpage using inline style and no css?

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to html and am asked to only use inline style when styling a website for a class and I don't have any idea how to. Im just wondering if anyone has any resources that would help?

Comment: Why can you not use a CSS file? It is really bad practice to use inline styles.

Comment: You can't. The only form of inline style that works in an HTML document is CSS (unless you are using Netscape 4 in which case you could use JSSS). Questions asking for links to tutorials are off-topic for Stackoverflow anyway.

Comment: unless you're talking about attributes like mentioned here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp, all inline styles are also CSS.

Comment: Inline styles :( Probably teaching Dreamweaver too :P

Comment: To clarify.  We are allowed to use CSS however it must be inline. I know it's bad practice but it's out of the scope of this class unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

To use inline styling, just add [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#style) attribute to your html elements. Note that inline styles are CSS.

For example:

```
<p style="color:red; font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; white-space:nowrap; border-radius:10px; margin: 10px; padding:10px; border:10px solid blue">Contents</p>
```

Anyway, this is not the recommended way of styling, because of [separation of presentation and contents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content).

Comment: I see. So is there an online resource that shows a list of the different code words and what they affect. Like border-radius and such.

Comment: @user3258789 You could read [MDN CSS tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started), and also see [MDN CSS reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference)